# Merging Branches Without Checkout

Tags: git, git-merge, git-checkout

Is there a way to merge a branch into another without checking out either branch? For example, I have branch 'master' checked out, but I want to merge branch-a into branch-b, without leaving master.

Comment: Other related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/git-update-a-local-branch-without-checking-it-out

Comment: See also [Update/pull a local Git branch without checking it out?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3216360/456814).

Comment: Duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3216360/456814).