# Merge branches without checking out branch

Tags: git, merge

I have 3 branches.

```
     master [ Live Server]
      \
       stage [ Stage Server Where we test changes; merge commits ]
        \ 
         Dev [ Local Machine ]
```

I would like to downstream the changes to. Each of these branches are set to tracking each other.

Normally, to downstream the changes i do this:

`git checkout stage && git merge master`

Then i checkout dev and i do the same

`git checkout dev && git merge stage`

Then push them all:
`git push origin --all`

Is there a way to downstream those changes without checking out into each branch?

I maybe using the wrong terminology. I'm not totally sure if i'm using upstream/downstream terminology correctly.

Comment: would master branch get your dev code as well?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm looking for.

Comment: Your usage of downstream isn't incompatible with what I understand about "upstream/downstream": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream/2749166#2749166

Comment: if you git merge master, master branch would not get your stage code, but only your stage branch get your master code...

Comment: @Kit Ho is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @Chris: It's a statement. `git checkout stage && git merge master` will merge changes from master into stage. It won't add any commits to master. I believe this is your intention, but your first reply to @Kit seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @Tom Anderson Yes it is. I meant the other way around. dev would get the commits from master.

Comment: yes. what i am pointing is exactly what @Chris say, i just wonder why you merge your master code to dev. branch. Dev. branch is supposed to have to newest commit in your whole repository.

Comment: @kit ho i do that but the changes need to be on the staging server too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging Branches Without Checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156957/merging-branches-without-checkout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git checkout-and-merge without touching working tree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1402993/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update/pull a local Git branch without checking it out?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3216360/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging without changing the working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408532/merging-without-changing-the-working-directory).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging Branches Without Checkout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4156957/456814).

Comment: Re-added: Possible duplicate of [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3216360/367456)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can indeed "merge" a branch B into branch A without having to check out branch A, **but only if it's a fast-forward merge**.

You can use a refspec with `fetch` to do the "merge". If merging branch B into branch A using `git merge` would result in a fast-forward merge, then you can do the following without having to checkout A:

```
git fetch <remote> B:A
```

### The Documentation

The above matches the refspec format

```
git fetch <remote> <source>:<destination>
```

From [the documentation for `git fetch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) (emphasis mine):

> The remote ref that matches `<src>` is fetched, and if `<dst>` is not empty string, **the local ref that matches it is fast-forwarded using** `<src>`.

### See Also

1. [Git checkout and merge without touching working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402993/git-checkout-and-merge-without-touching-working-tree)
2. [Merge, update, and pull Git branches without using checkouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216360/update-pull-a-local-git-branch-without-checking-it-out)
3. [Merging without changing the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408532/merging-without-changing-the-working-directory)
4. [Merging Branches Without Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156957/merging-branches-without-checkout)

Comment: (For the lazy who don't want to dig through the other answers):
You can also use a . in place of the the remote for operation on local branches.

Comment: This is such a good find. I've haphazardly passed this in the documentation a handful of times and never picked up on this.

Comment: @CarrieKendall it's really easy to miss. It's been a long while, but I think that the only reason I discovered this was because my bash auto-completed the refspec one day, and being curious, I decided to hit enter and see what would happen...

Comment: Here's a practical example: `git fetch . foo:master` this will do a fast-forward merge of foo into master no matter what branch you are on. The `.` refers to the local repository.

Answer (score 17):

Enter **git-forward-merge**:

> Without needing to checkout destination, `git-forward-merge <source> <destination>` merges source into destination branch.

https://github.com/schuyler1d/git-forward-merge

Answer (score 6):

You can't merge into a branch **in the general case** without having it checked out.  There's a good reason for this, however.  You need the proper working tree in order to denote and resolve merge conflicts.

Comment: This isn't a new comment, just editing out the link to my answer because, in hindsight, linking to my own answer like that was distasteful.

Edited comment: This isn't entirely correct. If the merge would result in a fast-forward merge, then there will be no conflicts, and thus it's not necessary to have a working copy, and thus it's possible to merge without having to have the destination branch checked-out.