# Can I pull to a branch other than the one I'm on?

Tags: git, branch, git-pull

I need to be able to pull to a branch that I might not be on (in fact, assume for the sake of argument I don't know what branch I'm on). For example, I have a remote `origin` with a branch `master` that is tracked locally in the usual way by a local `master` using a tracking branch. Are there options or arguments I can supply to `git-pull` that will have the same effect as switching to `master`, pulling, and then switching back to whatever branch I started on?

Many answers here suggest that this is not possible, but the [documentation's discussion](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) of `<dst>` under `<refspec>` suggests that something like

```
git pull origin master:master
```

will do the trick. Is that so?

Comment: It's what I use... " git pull origin mySourceBranch"

Comment: @Jahnux73: What is `mySourceBranch` in my scenario? Is it `master`, `master:master`, `remotes/origin/master` — or something else. I want the effect to be the same as if I'd pulled after switching to `master` (which has the usual tracking set up).

Comment: When I'm on branch 'feature' , when i make a 'git pull origin develop', it make a pull of 'develop branch' on my actual branch 'feature'. ( so master for you i think)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `git pull` basically does a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.

Doing `git pull` for another branch is not possible, because doing `git merge` for another branch is not possible. To be able to do `git merge`, you need to checkout the target branch first. For this same reason, you cannot do `git pull` for another branch.

[@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) added an excellent point:

> And, to specifically address git pull origin x:y: git pull passes the x:y argument to git fetch, so git fetch does what it does; but then git pull attempts to merge into the current branch, regardless of x and/or y.

See this also for reference:

[Merging Branches Without Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156957/merging-branches-without-checkout)

Comment: And, to specifically address `git pull origin x:y`: `git pull` passes the `x:y` argument to `git fetch`, so `git fetch` does what it does; but then `git pull` attempts to merge into the current branch, regardless of `x` and/or `y`.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen the master:master syntax. Generally: git pull origin  e.g. master.

I think what you want to do is do a fetch first. Then you have the ability to merge any of the tracking branches, or switch to them.

Comment: Nor had I, so I was surprised to see it in the docs — and surprised to see that it seemed to do what I wanted. (Remember I'm not asking about `fetch`: I'm asking specifically whether I can use `pull` in this way.)

Answer (score 0):

A pull is basically a fetch followed by a checkout of the updates on the current (tracking) branch. All you want is the fetch.

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

Comment: No, I really want the `pull`, but I see the problem with my question now: I'm trying to get the working tree files updated without switching branches. That makes no sense, right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the merge feature of `git pull`?

If not, you could simply do:

```
git fetch
git branch -f master origin/master
```

This simply makes the local master to point on the same commit, the remote master points to.